# conditional fields in node creation

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, database

Well Im trying to use some conditional fields while creating some type of nodes. for example

I have a content type called "organization" this content type has

name, logo, and some other stuff

also has a select box field where the user selects the type of organization, depending of what the user selects I need to show other fields that depends of the type of the organization.

There is a module for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Conditional Fields Module](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). Does exactly what you need.

You can also find nice tutorial here: [CFM Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5z-GrHvl7s8)